Aurora Postgres - Database per Tenant architecture issues
We have a multi-tenant SaaS app. We had been using a shared DB for all our tenants with TenantId as foreign key in all the tables. Everything had been working fine, till our business required DB (or Schema) per Tenant architecture.
We upgraded our backend (ASP.NET Core 8) to handle this architecture and ambitiously migrated all our tenants to a separate DB on a cluster. We have around 1000 DBs on the cluster and since our migration life has been very difficult. Where with the same amount of data and load even 32 GB 4 CPU r7g.xl instance seemed over-provisioned, now even 16 CPU 128 GB r7g.4xl AWS instance sometimes seems underprovisoned.
Out of 1000 DBs more than half won't even have more than 100 MB data. Few can have data in few GBs.
Since we had been using AWS DMS (serverless) also the replication had been inactive for some time. So came the warnings in vacuum after some time:
WARNING: oldest xmin is far in the past

When we checked all the possible reasons, it turned out replication slots are holding the xmin. Here is what the following query returns:
SELECT c.relnamespace::regnamespace as schema_name, c.relname as table_name,
greatest(age(c.relfrozenxid),age(t.relfrozenxid)) as age,
2^31-1000000-greatest(age(c.relfrozenxid),age(t.relfrozenxid)) as remaining
FROM pg_class c LEFT JOIN pg_class t ON c.reltoastrelid = t.oid
WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'm') ORDER BY 4;

Result:

The value is increasing, we tried deleting the replication slots two times, and each time it caused a downtime and cluster couldn't recover and we had to resort to creating a new cluster from backup. So the moment we delete the inactive replication slots this happens:

The insert/update queries which otherwise run fine, suddenly just after deleting the replicating slots start showing LW locks.
Here is how it looks like now (slots not deleted):

We have come to believe it is a mistake to have more than 300 DBs per cluster. So we will be using multiple clusters with around 300 DBs per cluster.
But what should we do now, and why deleting the replication slots triggers these locks?

The stale replication slots have prevented autovacuum from performing its maintenance job. Since your tables now contain unfrozen rows older than autovacuum_freeze_max_age transactions, autovacuum is launching anti-wraparound autovacuum runs which seem to consume enough resources to affect you application.
You could try the following: Set autovacuum_freeze_max_age to 1500000000 and vacuum_freeze_table_age and vacuum_freeze_min_age to 500000000. Then delete the stale replication slots. The changed settings will keep autovacuum from starting intense activity. Essentially, you are buying some time. Use that time to manually VACUUM (FREEZE) all tables for which age(pg_class.relfrozenxid) exceeds 100 million. See that you get done with that before you hit the increased limits. If you are successful, age(pg_database.datfrozenxid) will go below 200 million. Once you are done, reset the parameters to their default values.
If you don't take action, your database will at some point refuse new transactions, and you will have to take an extended down time to VACUUM the affected tables.

Thanks a lot for the solution. We will try this. Regarding replication slot deletion causing this issue what can be the reason? Even executing vacuum freeze post deletion didn't bring down the AAS.

Deleting the replication slot is harmless and even beneficial. What must have caused the problem is that only when the replication slots are gone, VACUUM can do its job. So before you drop the replication slots, you can run VACUUM all you want, it won't be able to do much work.

So deleting the slot would have triggered auto vacuums which caused LwLock:MultiXactGen? Anyway to avoid this lock if we remove replication slots - by changing parameter in postgres

No, VACUUM won't generate a multixact. I think that that is a red herring. If you allow 1000 database connections, they'll step on each others' feet. It's probably the increased load that pushes it over the brink.

The load did not change, this happened twice in prod, the moment we deleted relication slots and once after vacuum (analyze, verbose) - without passing table name so it vacuums pg_catalog tables too. The system works fine even for 3000-6000 connections. We lost DBContext pooling when we switched to DB per Tenant. But DB cluster is now plagued with MultiXactGen issues which we didn't face before.

The UPDATE queries start showing MultiXactGen the moment we deleted replication slots.

What would you recommend from a performance point of view - one DB with 300 schemas per cluster or 300 DBs per cluster?

My theory is that the increased load by the autovacuum runs that suddenly can do something after you dropped the replication slots was enough to cause performance problems. 300 databases per cluster are better, but also not good. Spread the load across several machines and reduce the number of connections for each.

We migrated around 300 DBs to another cluster and. then we were safely able to drop the replication slots on the first cluster and vacuum freeze dbs to fix the issue.

The problem with 300 DBs per cluster vs 300 Schemas per db (one db per cluster) is we loose on client connection pooling which increases DB connections by  a very large number. From 400 to ~1500 now. So what issues due you foresee with using separate schemas instead of DBs (given total count schemas or dbs remans same).

You have no effective connection pooling anyway, if you allow 1000 connections. But I see your point. Still, try with fewer schemas/databases per cluster.
